# commit monitor for tfs

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know of a tool like CommitMonitor (http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor) that can be used with TFS.

Answer (score 2):

- A built-in solution can be to use Team System Web Access (even if it's not exactly the same functionality as CommitMonitor, you can make a bookmark to the page showing the last commits) : http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2007/08/27/free-add-on-team-system-web-access-tswa-power-tool-by-microsoft.aspx

  - Or you can use TFS events service built you own monitor :
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vishalag/archive/2006/11/13/subscribe-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-event-workitemchangedevent.aspx
  - Or you can just configure TFS Power Tools to send you an email after each commit (using TFS Alerts also provided with TFS events service).

[EDIT] You can also look at these kind of TFS Dashboard : http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2009/09/09/tfs-work-item-manager-amp-tfs-project-dashboard.aspx

Comment: Using the TFS Power Toys you get a more powerful editor for email alerts (eg. being able to get alerts on commits that match certain criteria).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What I like about commit monitor is the fact that I get all the information I need in one screen. That is date, who did the commit and what files changed. In addition the indication in the tool bar telling me when a commit was done is great. Using the web access or emails does not supply all this information. The only option might be building my own monitor, but for that I would need time, and I'm not sure this is worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at : https://github.com/Vooban/TfsCommitMonitor which is our initial version, originally developped two years ago, we'll be updating it to revamp UI using WPF and optimize it.